# Open Android mobile app through javascript click function

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom, mobile-application

I am trying to open an installed android mobile application via html page in Chrome browser through javascript or jQuery click function.

It seems an anchor tag tap is working fine and opening an installed app but it's not allowing when I am trying to open an app with javascript click function, href is same still it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>  
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="openApp" href="intent://adjustify/#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.adjustify.android;end">click me 65</a>
</body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('openApp').click();
            }, 2000);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Tried many things but no luck, any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this one  `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#openApp').click();});`

Comment: Tried Both: 
$('#openApp').click(); 
$('#openApp').trigger('click');

Comment: You have two Jquery scripts in there. Remove the  jquery script inside `<head> ` tag, then place the last two `<script>` tags just above the ending `</body>` tag.